# Expression has changed after it was checked Loading componennt

Tags: angular, typescript

I have fond similar questions asked, but could not solve my issue.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'waiting',
  template: `
  <div class="waiting">
    <div *ngIf="isLoading" class="loader2"></div>
  <div>`
})

export class WaitingComponent {
  public isLoading: boolean;

  public constructor(private _authHttp: HttpService) {
    this._authHttp.request.subscribe((action: HttpAction) => {
      this.isLoading = action === HttpAction.Requested;//HttpAction.Requested returns 0 or 1
    });
  }
}
```

I have seen suggestions that value isLoading has to be changed in AfterViewInit. I can't figure out how to make it work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code shouldn't cause that error. There has to be something else.

Comment: `this.isLoading = action === HttpAction.Requested;` I feel like something is wrong with this line.

Comment: how about this `this.isLoading =  HttpAction.Requested` ?

Comment: @micronyks `this.isLoading = HttpAction.Requested` will return and exception, because return value of HttpAction.Requested is number, 0 or 1. `this.isLoading = action === HttpAction.Requested;` works fine, no issue there.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer unfortunately getting `inline template:2:9 caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'. `

Comment: Sounds like your `_authHttp` is running code outside Angulars zone.

Comment: why don't you check `action object` and try to get relevant property type of Boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work around you can use `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` or `zone.run(...)`

```
export class WaitingComponent {
  public isLoading: boolean;

  public constructor(private _authHttp: HttpService, cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this._authHttp.request.subscribe((action: HttpAction) => {
      this.isLoading = action === HttpAction.Requested;//HttpAction.Requested returns 0 or 1
      cdRef.detectChanges();
    });
  }
}
```

but I think the real issue is somewhere in `_authHttp`.

Comment: This did the trick. Maybe you are right, will take a look. Thanks